# Anyone know how to fix grainy bokeh in the background?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

[image: example image below]

I keep getting grainy renders. I used denoising and my samples are at 500. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Use more samples and try to avoid the default denoising (or use https://remingtongraphics.net/tools/d-noise/).